# Long On Promises, Short On Delivery

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

To: People who don't kiss

As far as i know, these things are a complete waste of time. I don't *want* to read the f@#king manual while chatting! Sorry if that was over the top. I didn't mean to make this message not safe for work, you know what I mean?
Anyways, mail me your thoughts.
Sealed with a kiss,

Chowzen

<sub>**Bonus: Where's the secret one?**</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This message has

> a lot of common (and not-so-common) acronyms expanded out.
>  AFAIK ("as far as I know")
>  CWOT ("complete waste of time")
>  RTFM ("read the f***ing manual")
>  OTT ("over the top")
>  NSFW ("not safe for work")
>  YKWIM ("you know what I mean")
>  MMYT ("mail me your thoughts")
>  SWAK ("sealed with a kiss")
>
>  And their first letters spell "ACRONYMS".

Comment: ...and the secret acronym?

Comment: I have literally never heard of any of those except NSFW.

Answer (score 2):

Addition to [@Deusovi's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/70326/1852), the secret acronym is in the first line

> To: People who don't KISS (Keep It Short and Simple)

Comment: There it is! Thanks, and a big +1. Welcome to Puzzling.SE!